# how to accept specified connection

Tags: c++, c, http

I am now facing a design question. I have made a shared library which can be used to send HTTP requests to my HTTP server. It offers `GET`, `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE` APIs, so the user can use them to send requests directly. However, someone else can also use TCP/IP to send their own HTTP requests to my server.
My question is, how can I check if a request comes from my library or not? 
Can anybody give me some suggestion?

Comment: You can't. Anything your library can send, so can someone else.

Comment: @Barmar How about add something like TLS? is it considerable?

Comment: Counter-question: Why do you need to check this?

Comment: @mac.ma No, that wouldn't work. If the code is running on their machine, it will have access to the same TLS certificate that your code uses.

Comment: @UnholySheep For security, just like question title ,it is a design

Comment: TLS has support for client authentication. How to implement that in your current code is a different matter.

Comment: @Barmar this is a bad story :(

Comment: If a program is running on a client's computer they can hack it however they want. That includes hacking your library. So implementing this kind of check would not provide much security at all, as anyone inclined to do so can bypass it very easily

Comment: you could try embedding a password or certificate into the library itself. This will make it harder for them to find it.

Comment: @kaylum after all,TLS is so complicated. it is so big for my library

Comment: You want security but you don't want to pay for it? It doesn't work that way. Security is complicated. You can try to roll your own security but I'm betting you will get it wrong. Many people smarter than us have tried and still results in vulnerabilities.

Comment: @Barmar they can tcpdump message as HTTP is not encrypted. they can get password, i think

Comment: @kaylum yes for what you said. it is a truth

Comment: @mac.ma TLS means HTTPS.

Comment: @Barmar Ok, i’ll think it. very thank you for your suggestions

Comment: You could put something in the [User-Agent request header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent).  That's easily spoofed, but at least you tried.

Comment: @Barmar "*you could try embedding a password or certificate into the library itself. This will make it harder for them to find it*" - harder for a casual hacker who doesn't want to dig into it, but certainly not impossible for someone who is actually dedicated to bypassing the security.

Comment: @PaulSanders others can do the same thing as i did, it could not be suitable

Comment: @RemyLebeau That's what I meant by "make it harder".

Answer (score 0):

You can use any "standard" method of authentication to verify that the requester is who they are supposed to be. Once you've determined the authenticity, provide the requester with a short term cookie that they must send with all requests. Reject any request that doesn't hold a valid cookie (except attempts to authenticate).

Technically this doesn't prevent requests from coming elsewhere other than your library. It merely restricts requests from sources that don't know your secret. But if you don't share the secret with anyone else, then you can limit yourself to only using your library which achieves the limitation to the library indirectly.